# How to get schedules description in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a scheduled pipeline in gitlab, whose description is "run everyday".

similar to this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html

How can I fetch this description when the pipeline runs? is there any CI variable which could give me the description?

Comment: These are all the pre-defined variables available in Gitlab. Doesn't look like that description can be fetched

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: I don"t think it's possible, but you can maybe define a variable on your schedule such as `MY_SCHEDULE_DESC` and define it as the same value as your schedule's description?

Answer (score 2):

You could configure a variable within the schedule run.

Then use it within your gitlab-ci.yml file to achieve what you wanted. (Like pierres comment)

Answer (score 0):

**I have good news!!**
Our friends at GitLab have been working on this feature. There is now a way to label your pipeline in release 15.5.1-ee.0!

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow

It uses the **workflow** control with a new keyword **name**

```
workflow:
    name: 'Pipeline for branch: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

You can even use the *workflow:rules* pair to have different names for you pipeline:

variables:
PIPELINE_NAME: 'Default pipeline name'

```
workflow:
    name: '$PIPELINE_NAME'
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
       variables:
           PIPELINE_NAME: 'MR pipeline: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS =~ /pipeline:run-in-ruby3/'
       variables:
           PIPELINE_NAME: 'Ruby 3 pipeline'
```

This feature is disabled by default in 15.5 because it is so new.

You can enable the feature flag, which is named *pipeline_name*.
 See this link to enable: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/feature_flags.html

You need to use the Rails Console to enable it. Pretty easy.

Note: Remember that the *workflow* keyword affects the entire pipeline instance.

Comment: I don't think that this is what OP is asking.  They want to access the scheduler name from within the .gitlab-ci.yml that is run, not the Pipeline name, preferably from some setting that already exists in GitLab.